# How to deploy a specific tf file (Terraform)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

I have 3 .tf files in my terraform root directory:

- vpc.tf
- subnets.tf
- instances.tf
- Along with the .terraform directory after running terraform init

I would like to deploy only vpc.tf running something like:

```
terraform apply vpc.tf #here, vpc.tf is a terraform file
```

But it doesn't work (I get a Go error: "zip: not a valid zip file"). 
If I just run

```
terraform apply
```

it will try to apply all configurations in all 3 terraform files (vpc.tf, subnets.tf and instances.tf) which is not what I want.
It seems that the way to have this to work is, have a completely different folder, and run something like

```
terraform apply vpc/ #here, vpc/ is a folder that containers vpc.tf file
```

which works. The problem with this approach, is that if I have 2 or more terraform files within the vpc/ folder, I come back to the first problem all over again.
It seems the solution for this is to have a specific resource in a specific folder, but this doesn't seem clean, as I can foresee that if the infrastructure grows, I will end up with several folders containing a few terraform files.
So the question is:

Is there a way to "terraform apply" a specific terraform file, and ignore all the rest within a folder? Am I missing something basic about terraform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can use `-target` as mentioned in [manojlds' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56591842/2291321) to target specific resources to run against at each time this is meant as a bit of an escape hatch for when you have something odd happening and need to ignore changes that would be applied to other resources in that area.

This is directly mentioned in the [Terraform documentation for `-target`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#resource-targeting):

> This targeting capability is provided for exceptional circumstances,
>   such as recovering from mistakes or working around Terraform
>   limitations. It is not recommended to use -target for routine
>   operations, since this can lead to undetected configuration drift and
>   confusion about how the true state of resources relates to
>   configuration.

Instead you should think about what things you are willing to change as a set and place `.tf` Terraform files that should be changed as a unit in the same directory and use the same state file for them.

If you don't want two things to be changed at the same time (eg setting up a VPC and also setting up an app that lives in that VPC or setting up test and production versions of an app) then these should be in different directories and use different state files.

This provides a nice separation of things, minimising blast radius, but still making it easier to apply out chunks of things that are related at the same time.

In your specific case I would question why you wouldn't want to apply both the VPC and subnets at the same time as this would typically just be considered part of the base networking config required for things to run in. Managing these together would normally make a lot of sense and allows you to do things like changing the name of the VPC also renaming the subnets in the same `apply`.

Comment: the reason I want to separate VPC and subnets, it's because we currently have 1 vpc already created, and many microservices sitting in the same vpc. This makes internal networking easy to set up. If I were to set up a vpc per microservice, I would also need to set up vpc peering if I want internal networking. I noted that most some people ill just have everything on 1 big terraform file (vpc, subnets, secgroups, routings, lb and autoscaling). Although i've found that this approach is good enough for replicating infrastructure, it doesn't allow reusability of smaller components.

Comment: Why do you want separate subnets per microservice? Honestly if you want that kind of networking separation then you are almost certainly better off with using the big ol' network separator of a VPC and peer as appropriate. I don't personally find that useful though and tend to have 1 VPC per region per AWS account. If things needs more separation then they also get a separate AWS account (eg test/prod or different teams having complete ownership).

Comment: ydaetskcoR, Subnetting is a networking concept designed for the purposes of a) splitting a network into smaller ranges if IP addresses and b) isolating traffic with routing. It makes perfect sense to use subnetting if one is looking to firewall between groups of machines if their existing network has the addresses to spare. I'm curious as to what reasoning you have to suggest creating a VPC instead?

Comment: @EvanB. I'm aware of subnetting but you wouldn't typically use subnetting for isolation of network resources other than on a public/private tier for AWS. Instead you use security groups as stateful firewalls rather than stateless NACLs that are the way you control traffic between subnets and are much more painful to manage traffic that way. Security groups should always be your preferred way of controlling network traffic inside the VPC.

Comment: ydaetskcoR, Network ACLs may be placed on subnets, which support all of the functionally provided by Security Groups while also supporting using a mixture of Allow/Deny logic. What about Network ACLs do you find "painful"? The interface is almost identical in the AWS dashboard these days.

Comment: NACLs can be a pain because you can't do particularly fine grained things (eg security group to security group) and are stateless so you need to allow ephemeral port return traffic which potentially allows for high port numbered traffic to also cross the NACLs (eg bridge based ECS services with dynamic port numbers use port numbers from 32768–61000). Security groups are a strictly better approach and NACLs are typically only recommended where they are required by some control measure that isn't amenable to change (eg regulatory).

Comment: If you're interested in pursuing this topic further it may be worth moving the discussion to chat or creating a question and linking back to this answer and the comment discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, which doesn't solve the exact need you have, but is doable is resource targeting using the `-target` argument, ex:

```
terraform plan -target digitalocean_loadbalancer.public -out run.plan
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#resource-targeting

Comment: downvoting because it's not an answer to the question, and terraform itself discourages the use of it.

Answer (score 0):

I read the entire discussion and honestly, it turned into an argument about proper ways to perform network segmentation. What the original question really asked was "how do I test standing up only a subset of resources, so that I don't have to bring the entire infrastructure up just to test a small piece of it?". Please, correct me if I am wrong, but that is what I feel the gist is. In the end, you will have to build up based on dependencies and throw in the rest of the pieces together, but at least you save time when testing the initial pieces that don't have any dependencies. Example: I am testing standing up a Cognito user pool that will eventually be used to authenticate requests sent to an API gateway, but I don't want to stand up that gateway while ironing out the kinks of the user pool.

Answer:

1. Use -target as **manojlds** suggested (not best practice, but efficient)
2. Put the file in a separate folder and go through the motions of init, plan, apply as **ydaetskcoR** suggested in his quite extensive answer (aligned with best practice)
3. Use AWS CLI equivalent to create what you want. This brings you out of the Terraform  lifecycle and allows you to perform quick-and-dirty changes to state of the resources without wearing the Terraform lifecycle straightjacket :). If, for some reason, you wish couple Terraform with the AWS CLI, use this (sorry, the code formatting is not that good here):

   resource "null_resource" "create-endpoint" {
   provisioner "local-exec" {
   command = "aws route53resolver create-resolver-endpoint --creator-request-id ${var.creator-request-id} --security-group-ids ${local.security-groups} --direction ${var.direction} --ip-addresses ${local.list-ip-template} --name ${var.endpoint-name} --tags ${var.tags} --profile ${var.aws-profile} > ${data.template_file.log_name.rendered}"
   }
   }